# Memory game timer card reset

Tags: c#

I'm making a memory game and i need to set a timer to reset de images if they don't match but it doesn't work to turn the pictures back to hidden:

```
//set images
if (clickedLabel != null)
{
    var Index = Convert.ToInt32(clickedLabel.Tag);
    clickedLabel.Image = icons[Index];

    //Check first clicked
    if (firstClicked == null)
    {
        firstClicked = clickedLabel;
        return;
    }

    secondClicked = clickedLabel;

    timer1.Start();
}
```

Method `timer1_Tick`:

```
//Timer
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();

    firstClicked = null;
    secondClicked = null;
}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not an adequate problem description. What doesn't work? What does it do, and how does that compare to what you expected it to do?

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
class YourClass
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    void YourMethod()
    {
        //code
        if (clickedLabel != null)
        {
            var Index = Convert.ToInt32(clickedLabel.Tag);
            clickedLabel.Image = icons[Index];

            //Check first clicked
            if (firstClicked == null)
            {
            firstClicked = clickedLabel;
            return;
        }

        secondClicked = clickedLabel;

        SetTimer();
    }

    private static void SetTimer ()
    {
        //System.Timers.Timer aTimer; at the beginning of your class
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer (2000); //the time you want in milliseconds
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The AutoReset set to false will make the Elapsed event trigger only once. Then, you do what you want in that event.

```
private static void OnTimedEvent (Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{
    firstClicked = null;
    secondClicked = null;
}
```

You might want to use Stop and Dispose methods on aTimer when you don't need it anymore.

You also should be more specific when posting questions, to be sure to have the help you need :)

Comment: Where should i put aTimer in System.Timers.Timer aTimer;? because it doesn't allow this